# Can you call OpenSSL's hash primitives from Java?

Tags: java, openssl, hash

Has anyone developed JNI bindings to call OpenSSL's hash functions from Java?

I am aware that Java has hash functions built in. The problem is that these run at only a third the speed of the OpenSSL native implementations. There is an [OpenSSL-Java project on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-java/files/), but it has no files to download.

My goal here is actually not to call OpenSSL, it is to overcome Java's suboptimal performance regarding hashing.

Comment: Could you give some examples of poor performance in Java's hashing implementations? This hashing doesn't have anything to do with authentication, does it? In authentication, you want *slow* hashing.

Comment: Are You sure that this bit of code is causing a performance problem with your application? If it's not, then you gain nothing by making it faster.

Comment: @Adam --- Sure. I am developing forensic software that needs to compute the MD5 hash for every sector on a hard drive. So that's roughly 2 billion hashes of 512-byte blocks each. My previous testing showed that Java did block hashes 1/3 the speed as OpenSSL.   And yes, I am sure that the hash speed is a limiting factor in this code.

Comment: Unfortunately then you are in a bit of a bind. Jumping through the java->jni barrier is very expensive. The speedup in executing the c code will likely be offset by the jni invoke. You can make your code MT, or perhaps look at something like azul zing if you have budget.

Comment: @Time4tea, thanks for the note. I didn't realize that Java->JNI was expensive. Unfortunately, making code MT doesn't speed it up, because I could just use pure C code multi-threaded, and it would be faster too!

Comment: @vy32: can you, please, show your code for MD5, JNI calls are not cheap at any rate, but it's hard to believe MD5 is so slow. Are you sure you are running -server. Bit twiddling in java is quite decent. C alike code in java runs just like C.

Comment: ... MD5 can be easily rewritten (around 200 lines of code or so) to work w/ the direct buffers, so no need to copy the memory either. Yet, I seriously doubt it'd help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://www.nayuki.io/page/native-hash-functions-for-java they implement hash functions in `c`, `x86 assembly` and `x86-64 assembly`

Boost up to 1.68× for SHA-256, but I see no difference with small files.

So If you tend to use with small file, I suggest stick with java.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe you have to write a C routine that not only calculated the hashes, but also does the file IO. Don't forget to use memory mapped IO for speed, else the limiting part is you copying buffers.

Comment: If I'm doing both the I/O and the hashing in C, then what's the point of using Java?

Comment: the GUI? Further features? Whatever, in this case just do it in C.

Comment: I think that you are missing the point of my question. I want to do it in Java so that the single executable can be run on multiple platforms.

Comment: So you already identified Java to be slow, and believe anyone can hash faster than by doing effictive IO like the openssl libs. Great, and a good point to downvote my answer. You are my hero.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you can but it's because of JNI you don't get the performance boost.